# Hangfire using a cancellation token

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have a recurrent job, and depending on a circumstance/event, I have to stop and delete a specific recurrent job and its running instance (it might be running or not).

Deleting the recurrent job is easy. To stop a running job, from what I learned, I have to use a cancellation token. The problem is: How can I persist a cancellation token? Is there any way to store it in a database and use it later?

Answer (score 1):

The expression you provide to BackgroundJob.Enqueue just needs a method inside with a CancellationToken as one of its arguments. Hangfire will provide you one which will stop the job when signalled to cancel.

Ie.

```
    public void LongRunningMethod(CancellationToken token) { /* work done */ }
    
    // called like so - Hangfire replaces the "None" token for you
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => LongRunningMethod(CancellationToken.None));
```

See Hangfire documentation: [using-cancellation-tokens](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-cancellation-tokens.html)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue in the past and I found a workaround.
I have compiled some **pseudo code** for you below, I hope this helps.

```
public void DeleteRunningHangfireJob(string methodName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(methodName)) {
            var monitor = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();

            var processingJobs = monitor.ProcessingJobs(0, int.MaxValue);
            var enqueuedJobs = monitor.EnqueuedJobs(0, int.MaxValue);

            processingJobs.Where(o => o.Value.Job.Method.Name == methodName).ToList().ForEach(x => { BackgroundJob.Delete(x.Key); });
            enqueuedJobs.Where(o => o.Value.Job.Method.Name == methodName).ToList().ForEach(x => { BackgroundJob.Delete(x.Key); });
        }
    }
```